# PHP cookie array works with integers but not strings

Tags: php, cookies

This code correctly creates a cookie, and then returns an array.

```
$exampleString1 = 123;
$exampleString2 = 456;

$exampleStringArray =  array();
$exampleStringArray[] = $exampleString1;
$exampleStringArray[] = $exampleString2;

$exampleStringArrayEncoded = json_encode($exampleStringArray);
setcookie('exampleCookie', $exampleStringArrayEncoded, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");


if(isset($_COOKIE['exampleCookie'])) {
    $exampleCookie = $_COOKIE['exampleCookie'];
    $exampleCookieDecoded = json_decode($exampleCookie);
    var_dump($exampleCookieDecoded);
}
```

However this does not work when the array contains strings by changing the first lines to:

```
$exampleString1 = 'abc';
$exampleString2 = 'def';
```

The dumped value is simply NULL

Can anyone explain why I am unable to store strings in a cookie?

Comment: I've just tested your code on my server and it works fine. I got the corresponding int and string as results. Nothing like NULL

Comment: I agree with Hans, this code works fine in my server. Are you positively sure you've shared the exact test case that exhibits the issue?

Comment: Absolutely. I answered my own question below - It required stripslashes() before json_decode() and now works flawlessly. I stumbled upon this suggestion from another stackoverflow answer and was surprised this information was so buried. I guess if it's specific to something on my local environment that could be why. PHP 5.6 for the record.

Answer (score 1):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the **next page
>   load** with the $_COOKIE array.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: On the next page load, this does not work either. Even if I do the var_dump($exampleCookieDecoded) before the rest of the code. It does work with integers so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove escaped quotes before the json_decode. Why json_decode doesn't do this itself, I have no idea.

```
$exampleCookie = stripslashes($_COOKIE['exampleCookie']);
$exampleCookieDecoded = json_decode($exampleCookie, true);
```

Comment: What escaped quotes are you talking about? The code you've share should not produce any. To be honest, I'm still to find a real life situation where `stripslashes()` is the solution.

Comment: In fact this reminds of good old [magic quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), but the feature itself was removed many years ago :-?

Comment: I think it is the escape characters from the encoded cookie. I'm really new to cookies but not doing anything complex here and this solution worked immediately.